# Opening drivers in ida

Tags: driver, ida

I have been trying to open some driver .sys files in ida pro. However even after running as administrator it says "Permission denied: choose another file." Is there a way to work around this?
I am  using Windows 10 professional if that helps.

Comment: Are you trying to open the .sys file from a protected folder? Try copying it to desktop, the try again with ida.